# Avoid vertical space above bullet list in LaTeX table

Tags: tables, itemize, enumitem

I have a [bullet list within a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329008/bullet-point-list-inside-of-a-table), but it has unwanted white space above the list, making it horizontally unaligned with other cells in the row.  Starting the list with [`\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86054/how-to-remove-the-whitespace-before-itemize-enumerate) helps a bit, but the problem persists.  **Is there a way to get rid of the space?**

Here is my minimal working example consisting of 4 code pattern combinations from [the above link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86054/how-to-remove-the-whitespace-before-itemize-enumerate):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Hello world.

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedright}p{3in}}
\toprule
   Item title \#1
   &
   \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt] % Code pattern 1
   \item Two
   \item bullets
   \end{itemize}
\tabularnewline[0.1in]
   Item title \#2
   &
   \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt] % Code pattern 1, 2nd row
   \item Two more
   \item bullets
   \end{itemize}
\tabularnewline[0.1in]
   Item title \#3
   &
   \kern-\parskip\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt] % Code pattern 2
   \item Another two
   \item bullets
   \end{itemize}\kern-\parskip
\tabularnewline[0.1in]
   Item title \#4
   &
   \kern-\parskip\begin{itemize} % Code pattern 3
   \item Another two more
   \item bullets
   \end{itemize}\kern-\parskip
\tabularnewline[0.1in]
   Item title \#5
   &
   \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=-8pt] % Code pattern 4
   \item Another two more
   \item bullets still
   \end{itemize}
\tabularnewline \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is the compiled result:

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580153/134144 could be interesting.

Comment: I got lost in all the code for the various effects, but focused on what might be the key bit: `tabitemize`.  I found my way to [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292053/how-to-produce-this-table-in-latex-with-inconsistent-lists-items/292087) and discovered that `\vspace{-1em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]` got rid of the space.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And a simpler table without lists?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\xxx{\par\hangindent1em\makebox[1em][l]{$\bullet$}}
\begin{tabular}{lp{2in}}\toprule
   Item title \#1 & \xxx Two  \xxx bullets \\\addlinespace
   Item title \#2 & \xxx Two more \xxx bullets \\\addlinespace
   Item title \#3 & \xxx Another two \xxx bullets \\\addlinespace
   Item title \#4 & \xxx Another two more \xxx bullets \\\addlinespace
   Item title \#5 & \xxx Another two more \xxx bullets with a long item taking more than one line.  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have to say, this is one of the most elegant solutions.  Minimal code, easy to read.  Thanks!

Comment: +1: I was laughing in my head about the name of the `\newcommand` :).

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet, 
                     leftmargin=*,
                     nosep, 
                     before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\raggedright, 
                     after=\end{minipage}}
```

to your preamble and use `tabitemize` instead of `itemize`. No need for manual adjustments any more:

[image]

In the following MWE, I also replaced `>{\raggedright}` with `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}`. With this modified code, you can use the regular `\\`  instead of `tabularnewline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%%% added:
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet, 
                     leftmargin=*,
                     nosep, 
                     before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\raggedright, 
                     after=\end{minipage}}



\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3in}}
\toprule
   Item title \#1
   &
   \begin{tabitemize}
   \item Two
   \item bullets
   \end{tabitemize}\\
   Item title \#2
   &
   \begin{tabitemize}
   \item Two more
   \item bullets
   \end{tabitemize}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, leandriis.  This code makes it clear to me that there's a lot I need to learn about the fundamentals of LaTeX (and enumitem, which is new to me).  I tend to hack and slash code patterns without really understanding the details.

Answer (score 2):

I defined a new list type with the relevant parameters and used  a `compress` command (borrowed from an answer on this site) that makes latex believe  lists are at the beginning of a minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize,1]{noitemsep, label=\textbullet, topsep=0pt, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

Hello world.\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedright\compress}p{3in}}
\toprule
   Item title \#1
   & \begin{tabitemize}
   \item Two
   \item bullets
   \end{tabitemize}
\tabularnewline[0.1in]
   Item title \#2
   & \begin{tabitemize}
   \item Two more
   \item bullets
   \end{tabitemize}
\tabularnewline[0.1in]
   Item title \#3
   & \begin{tabitemize}
   \item Another two
   \item bullets
   \end{tabitemize}
\tabularnewline[0.1in]
   Item title \#4
   & \begin{tabitemize}
   \item Another two more
   \item bullets
   \end{tabitemize}\kern-\parskip
\tabularnewline[0.1in]
   Item title \#5
   & \begin{tabitemize}
   \item Another two more
   \item bullets still
   \end{tabitemize}
\tabularnewline \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Bernard.  I think this is going to be the source of education on my part...I just need to find the bandwidth to follow-up and delve into it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *leandriss*, I found my way to [this
page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292053/how-to-produce-this-table-in-latex-with-inconsistent-lists-items/292087)
and discovered the answer with some experimentation:
`\vspace{-1em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Hello world.

\begin{tabular}{l>{\raggedright}p{3in}}
\toprule
   Item title \#1
   &
   \vspace{-1em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt] % Code pattern 1
   \item Two
   \item bullets
   \end{itemize}
\tabularnewline[0.1in]
   Item title \#2
   &
   \vspace{-1em}\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,topsep=0pt] % Code pattern 1, 2nd row
   \item Two more
   \item bullets
   \end{itemize}
\vspace{-1em} \tabularnewline \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Here is the compiled result:

[image]

Unfortunately, `\vspace{-1em} \tabularnewline \bottomrule` doesn't get
rid of the space at the bottom, and `\tabularnewline \vspace{-1em} \bottomrule` generates an error.  I can live with that.

Comment: The top lines don't quite line up.  `\vspace{-1\baselineskip}` might be more precise.  I don't have any useful suggestions for the excess space below.

Comment: Thanks, barbara beeton.  I found that if I use `\tabularnewline` instead of `tabularnewline[0.1in]` after `\toprule`, there is space at the very top, but it seems balance with the gap at the bottom.  Plus, it seems consistent with the gaps between rows.  However, this might be a side effect of the organizational template that I'm using.